# How to costumize Terminal on Lubuntu like Mint

Tags: lxterminal

How to customize terminal Lubuntu likes Mint?

If in mint at myhome directory /home/akhfiya:

```
olivia akhfiya#
```

but in lubuntu:

```
akhfiya@olivia:/home/akhfiya/#
```

I confused how to change terminal lubuntu like mint.

Answer (score 0):

That has nothing to do with the terminal. Edit the shell's startup file, e.g. `~/.bashrc`, and [redefine `$PS1`](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tip-prompt/).

Comment: how to do this, i was on ~/.bashrc. but i understand with the code $PS1.  Could you give me an example? :) to change like mint. 
Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with the examples in the article?

Comment: OK. OK. I will try, My english language is not good. So this article is not understood by me. :) i'm sorry.

Comment: The article will be there a while longer, so take your time reading it. And anything I would write would be written as the article, so that wouldn't help you regardless.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help. Nice to chat with you. :)